# как удалить вирус майнер xmrig?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, вирусы

как удалить вирус майнер xmrig?
обнаружил такой процесс который сильно грузить процессор.

```
./xmrig --algo=cryptonight --url=xmr-eu2.nanopool.org:14444 --user=42y1QFBDSVmXZbvZ+

sudo ls -l /proc/31383/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul 28 13:09 /proc/31383/exe -> /tmp/xmrig
```

как его полностью удалить из системы?

Comment: `kill -9 \`pidof xmrig\``? Кавычки только как у команды на выполнение

Comment: Насколько я понял вы предлагаете убить процесс и все? Я уже убил его и удалил /tmp/xmrig.
Вопрос в том, как узнать где исполнимые файлы этой заразы? Возможно ее код где-то остался. 
apt get uninstall  xmrig вообще не находил ее изначально

Comment: Поместить на месте где жил вирус файл нулевой длинны, с таким же именем и дать ему атрибут, [тут](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)) и [тут](http://www.aboutlinux.info/2005/11/make-your-files-immutable-which-even.html) потом разбираться кто его создает. Какое левое ПО у вас стоит? НодаЖс ? :) и модули разных авторов?

Comment: nodejs нету, только vestacp exim fileban. Нету какого ни будь антивируса который это может удалить? Или предотвратить?

Comment: включать аудит и ждать повторного заражения. Кстати монтирование /tmp/ с `noexec` - хорошая идея

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите узнать кто читает или пишет в файл и потом удалить все по цепочке

```
~# lsof /path/to/file
```

Если хотите убить все связанные процессы с патерном "xmring"

```
~# pkill -9 -f xmring
```

Если хотите удалить бинарник и все активные файлы

```
~# ps aux | awk '/[x]mrig/ {print $11}' | xargs rm -r
```

Можете попытаться найти скрипт инициализации и удалить его тоже

```
~# find / -type f -exec grep -l "xmrig" {} \; | xargs rm -r
```

google: linux antivirus - вам в помощь в поиске антивируса для *nix

Вы про этот?

https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig

> XMRig is a high performance Monero (XMR) CPU miner, with official
>   support for Windows. Originally based on cpuminer-multi with heavy
>   optimizations/rewrites and removing a lot of legacy code, since
>   version 1.0.0 completely rewritten from scratch on C++.

Comment: Да он там наверняка упакован, так что скрипт так найти вряд-ли, или ещё проще, он его с инета тянет..

Comment: @NewView lsof пробовали? что за дистрибутив у вас, Как вы поняли, что этот "вирус" поставлен через apt?

Comment: Один нюанс, вирус не у меня :) но судя по строке и симптомам это манер *коинов :)

Comment: ubuntu 16.10. подумал что через apt, теперь думаю что через php. Если его ставили через php то где-то есть и файл который его установил?

Comment: @ВикторЛернер не могу понять почему вы думаете, что это вирус? пробовали мой ответ?

Comment: Если бы читали мои комментарии выше, то увидели что я убил этот процесс и удалил этот файл, а вместо него создал пустой файл с правами 000.
Если вам так угодно называйте его трояном)) 
Ваш ответ не помог, нечего не нашлось